# QueryDSL - Delete ManyToMany association

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, querydsl

Been having a hard day trying to figure out a better way to delete an element from a List in a Many to Many association.

Example:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable
    private List<B> b;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    private Long id;
}

/*
* This works.
*/
public boolean removeB(long aId, long bId) 
{
    A a = getRepository().findOne(aId);

    for (B b : a.b) {
        if(b.id.equals(bId))
        {
            return a.b.remove(b);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/*
* This fails: "You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause"
*/
public boolean removeB(long aId, long bId)
{
    QA qa = QA.a;
    return getQueryFactory()
            .delete(qa)
            .where(qa.id.eq(aId).and(qa.b.any().id.eq(bId)))
            .execute() > 0;
}
```

The first method removeB works but it uses a vanilla way of removing the association causing too much processing.

I'd like to use QueryDSL

Thank you!